# Using sim900a GSM module, sending data to xampp Database

Tags: arduino-uno, gsm

I am using a soil moisture sensor, dht11, and a relay module. To send data to xampp (database) sever I used the sim900a GPRS module and wrote a PHP code as well. But it doesn't connect and pass data to the database.
what is the problem?

Ardunio code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>                           //GSM module Library
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8);                      //GSm module pin configration
#include <String.h>                                   //Header file
#include <DHT.h>                                      //Moisture sensor library
#define DHTPIN A1                                     //Define humidity sensor as Analog pin 1
#define soilHumPIN A0                                 //Define Soil moisture sensor as Analog pin 0

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHT11);                               //Specify the DHT sensor
int relayEnable = 4;                                  //Define the digital pin to which dc water pump is to be connected
int soilHum = 0;                                      //Integer to store soil moisture value.
int output_value ;                                    //Integer to store the output value of soil moiture sensor
int current_value;                                    //Integer to store current value of soil moisture sensor reading
int threshold = 320;                                  //set the threshold value = 320
const int analogOutPin = 8;                           //Set analog output pin to pin 1

void setup()
{
  gprsSerial.begin(9600);                             // the GPRS baud rate
  Serial.begin(9600);                                 // the baud rate
  pinMode(relayEnable, OUTPUT);                       //set relayEnable pin as OUPUT
  dht.begin();

  delay(1000);
}

void loop()
{
  float humid = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();
  output_value = analogRead(soilHum);                 //read the value of soil moisture sensor and store it in output_value
  current_value = output_value;                       //set current_value equal to output_value
  output_value = constrain(output_value, 10, 1023);   //set the contrain on output_value. Minimum = 10 Maximum = 1023
  output_value = map(output_value, 10, 1023, 100, 0); //map the output_value
  analogWrite(analogOutPin, output_value);            //send the output_value to transmitter pin
  delay(100);

  Serial.print("Temperature = ");                     //Print Temperature
  Serial.print(t);                                    //Serial print
  Serial.println(" °C");                              //Print temperature in Celcius
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");                        //Print Humidity
  Serial.print(humid);                                    //Serial print
  Serial.println(" %");                               //Print Humidity as a precentage value
  Serial.print("Soil Moisture = ");                   //print Moisture=
  Serial.print(output_value);                         //print the output_value
  Serial.println("%");                                //print %

if(current_value >=threshold)                                        //check if current_value >= 800
   
   {
    //if yes then
    Serial.println("\nWater Level Low... Turning Solenoid on..");       //print water level low.. turning water pump on..
    digitalWrite(relayEnable,LOW);                                     //turn on the dc water pump
    
    
   }
   else
   {
    //if no then
    Serial.println("\nWater Level High... Turning Solenoid off");       //print water level high.. turning water pump off..
    digitalWrite(relayEnable,HIGH);                                      //turn off the dc water pump
    
   }
   delay(10000);                                                        //create a delay of 10 second
   
  if (gprsSerial.available())
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());

  gprsSerial.println("AT");                           //Checking the status
  delay(1000);

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CPIN?");                    //Pin code of the sim is accepted or not
  delay(1000);

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CREG?");                   //Gives information about access technology
  delay(1000);

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT?");                 //Attach or deattach pacakge domain service
  delay(1000);

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSHUT");               //GPRS tcp contact
  delay(1000);

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");             //Reteun the connection status
  delay(2000);

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");              //Device single or multi ip address
  delay(2000);

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CSTT=\" \"");   //start task and setting the APN, for dialog APN is blank
  delay(1000);

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIICR");             //bring up wireless connection
  delay(3000);

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIFSR");           //get local IP adress
  delay(2000);

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSPRT=0");   //echo is prompt or not
  delay(3000);

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"IP/fruitinfo/insertDB.php\",\"3306\"");//start up the connection
  delay(6000);

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSEND");         //begin send data to remote server
  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();

  //Sending data to server
  String str = "GET fruitinfo/insertDB.php";
  Serial.println(str);
  gprsSerial.println(str);            //begin send data to remote server

  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println((char)26);               //sending
  delay(5000);                                //waitting for reply, important! the time is base on the condition of internet
  gprsSerial.println();

  ShowSerialData();

  gprsSerial.println("AT+CIPSHUT");           //close the connection
  delay(100);
  ShowSerialData();
}
void ShowSerialData()
{
  while (gprsSerial.available() != 0)
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  delay(5000);

}
```

PHP code insertDB:

```
<?php
     
    require 'database_connection.php';
 
    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
        // keep track post values
        $soil_moisture = $_POST['soil_moisture'];
        $solenoid = $_POST['solenoid'];
        $humid = $_POST['humid'];
        
        
        // insert data
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO fruit_details (soil_moisture,solenoid,humid) values(?, ?, ?)";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($soil_moisture,$solenoid,$humid,));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: user data.php");
    }
?>
```

database_connection php code

```
<?php
    class Database
    {
        private static $dbName = 'fruitdb' ;
        private static $dbHost = 'localhost' ;
        private static $dbUsername = 'root';
        private static $dbUserPassword = 'hesn2412tutoo2';
         
        private static $cont  = null;
         
        public function __construct() {
            die('Init function is not allowed');
        }
         
        public static function connect()
        {
           // One connection through whole application
           if ( null == self::$cont )
           {     
            try
            {
              self::$cont =  new PDO( "mysql:host=".self::$dbHost.";"."dbname=".self::$dbName, self::$dbUsername, self::$dbUserPassword); 
            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
              die($e->getMessage()); 
            }
           }
           return self::$cont;
        }
         
        public static function disconnect()
        {
            self::$cont = null;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: write a test sketch and test php script for testing the connection between the arduino and php server ... proceed with code for connecting to database only after connection to php server is established

Comment: @jsotola I have written a php code and modified arduino code using this command AT+HTTPPARA="URL","(http://axxxxxxxxxx.com/conn.php?&humid=87&temp=27.5&soil_moisture=76\"r"\). This will save in xampp database as  87, 27.5 and 76. To send another data I need to modifed above parameters manually. How to get the sensor values automatcally to post it in xampp database?